# Windows 7 Sysprep Default User

Tags: windows-7, sysprep

I seem to be having a problem with implementing my sysprep.

I have been playing with Windows 7, WAIK, Server 2008 R2 and various other things. I managed to create a WIM with everything I need installed and I have worked out the autounattend.xml. I now have a Windows 7 64-bit complete unattended install from a USB device. It has all my programs, setting and everything done except one thing - the default profile set up 100% correctly.

I have created a mostly set up default profile. I booted into audit mode, customized the Administrator account (mostly anyway) and then used sysprep with an unattend.xml file containing the `copyprofile=true` command. The file was set up with the WSIM and does not contain any extra info.

This all works wonderfully. I recreated the WIM and all was good. I then decided to move the default location of the visible stuff in the user profile (Documents, Music, Pictures etc.) without changing the location of Appdata or other hidden folders. This is where things went a little... wrong.

I went to the user folder (generally has the User name) with all the other folders in it. I right clicked on My Documents, found the location tab and changed it to M:\Documents. Now if I run `sysprep /generalize /oobe /reboot /unattend:unattend.xml` it starts the generalise... then spits out a fatal error and goes no further.

The setuperr.log contains the following errors:

```
2011-08-18 23:21:43, Error      [0x0f0043] SYSPRP WinMain:The sysprep dialog box returned FALSE
2011-08-18 23:31:57, Error      [0x0f0082] SYSPRP LaunchDll:Failure occurred while executing 'C:\Windows\System32\slc.dll,SLReArmWindows', returned error code -1073425657
2011-08-18 23:31:57, Error      [0x0f0070] SYSPRP RunExternalDlls:An error occurred while running registry sysprep DLLs, halting sysprep execution. dwRet = -1073425657
2011-08-18 23:31:57, Error      [0x0f00a8] SYSPRP WinMain:Hit failure while processing sysprep generalize internal providers; hr = 0xc004d307
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I can redirect My Documents and other items in a user file to a second drive in the default profile so it affects each person logging in?

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain you can't manage the **My Documents** folder that way.  You'll need to either edit the local security policy/local group policy, build a script to re-map it, or use Group Policy for after the computer is set up and joined to the domain.

In certain instances, where some networks don't have Active Directory to use Group Policy, using the local group policy should work.

Here's an [example](http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/tools/14324.html)

More [info](http://blogs.technet.com/b/fdcc/archive/2008/05/07/lgpo-utilities.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I had to do similar task in past. Tried to use WAIK methods to redirect profile folder - no good. Tried to use symlinks for transparent work of OS - still no good, OS couldn't complete setup in that case. The way that worked is to change registry of Default User profile and write new folder locations there. After that anyone who log in get their work folders (Docs, Music, Pictures, etc.) redirected to new location, and hidden forder remain at defaul location. Here are registry keys that must be changed (Default user registry was imported as "DefaultProfile" under HKLM):

```
"HKLM\DefaultProfile\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v Desktop
"HKLM\DefaultProfile\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v Favorites
"HKLM\DefaultProfile\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v "My Music"
"HKLM\DefaultProfile\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v "My Pictures"
"HKLM\DefaultProfile\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v "My Video"
"HKLM\DefaultProfile\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v Personal
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to the rearm count.  If it hit zero with this try, this could be unrelated to the default user.